# How to set the default parameter value for jdbc inbound-channel-adapter?

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, spring-integration

I have jdbc inbound-channel-adapter with select parametrized query.
How to set the default parameter value?

Comment: You need to show the configuration.

Comment: Thanx for reply. Post my solution.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use something like `ExpressionEvaluatingSqlParameterSourceFactory.createParameterSourceNoCache(null)`:

```
/**
 * Create an expression evaluating {@link SqlParameterSource} that does not cache it's results. Useful for cases
 * where the source is used multiple times, for example in a {@code <int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter/>} for the
 * {@code select-sql-parameter-source} attribute.
 * @param input The root object for the evaluation.
 * @return The parameter source.
 */
public SqlParameterSource createParameterSourceNoCache(final Object input) {
```

There is no something like "default parameter value", but you can emulate it with the SpEL's Elvis operator for the particular parameter name. See `public void setParameterExpressions(Map<String, String> parameterExpressions) {` of the mentioned factory.

Comment: Thanx for reply. Post my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Solve it with creation class:

```
public class SqlParameterTransfer extends AbstractSqlParameterSource {

public void setValue(String key) {
    synchronized (lock) {
        this.key = key;
    }
}

@Override
public String getValue(String paramName) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    String value = null;
    if (KEY_PARAM_NAME.equals(paramName)) {
        value = key;
    }
    return value;
}

@Override
public boolean hasValue(String paramName) {
    return KEY_PARAM_NAME.equals(paramName);
}

private static final String KEY_PARAM_NAME = "key";
private Object lock = new Object();
private String key = "default_value";
```

}

Then use it in inbound-channel-adapter in this way (through the bean):

```
<int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter  
    ...
    select-sql-parameter-source="sqlParameterTransfer">
    ...
</int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter>
```